# Big file creation on IIS with crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, crystal-reports

I want to know if there has been any issues on creating big files on IIS with crystal reports.

Te issue is get is this i create reports that are bigger than 800 megs, it works fine when i do this locally howeer as soon as i try to generate these reports on my IIS server this does not work .

I run the website on IIS 7 with windows 2008 r2 x64

Is there any issues with generating large files on IIS 7 with crystal reports?

EDIT: Files that are not generating are bigger than 800 megs and they do not generate at all on the server. Though on my machine they do generate. 
The applications simply times out on the server.

Comment: I'd bet you're reaching memory limits, and that this would be a better fit at serverfault.com.  That's just a guess, though.  I have a similar issue I'm dealing with now, so I'll be watching your question to see what you find.

Comment: What do you mean `this does not work`?  Do you get an error message, a timeout or simply no report?

Comment: it simply times out... ive been looking ait the folder when doign the request and the file simply isnt created.

Comment: @Lunatikzx: If you work with asp.net then page time out issue come many time with IIS.

Comment: is there a way to avoid that timeout